# Finding word count for a given string

Tags: java

I wrote a program to implement to find the count of words for a given string.

I have applied two different approaches.

The test works for these two approaches and I am looking for other approaches to solve this problem.

Thanks for your valuable comments advance.

```
package test;

import main.algorithms.WordCount;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class WordCountTest {

    WordCount wc;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        wc = new WordCount();
    }

    @Test
    public void testWordCount(){

        String str = "nesly amazon google facebook apple";

        Assert.assertEquals(5,wc.countWords(str));

        Assert.assertEquals(5,wc.countWordsTokenizer(str));
    }

}


package main.algorithms;

import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class WordCount {

    public int countWords(String str)
    {
        int end = 0;
        int in = 1;

        int state = end; int wc = 0; int i = 0;

        while (i < str.length())
        {
            if(str.charAt(i) == ' ' || str.charAt(i) == '\n'
                    || str.charAt(i) == '\t')
                state = end;

            else if (state == end)
            {
                state = in;
                ++wc;
            }
            ++i;
        }
        return wc;
    }

    public int countWordsTokenizer(String str){

        return new StringTokenizer(str).countTokens();
    }



}
```

Comment: The two approaches could not return the same result  because `StringTokenizer` compares chars with `\f` while `countWords` method doesn't.

Comment: `length` of `String.split()`

Answer (score 4):

Your approach works well but it doesn't consider punctuation, for example:

```
@Test
public void testWordCount(){
    String str = "Hey — how are you?";

    assertEquals(4, wc.countWords(str)); // Fail
    assertEquals(4, wc.countWordsTokenizer(str)); // Fail
}
```

Also `StringTokenizer` is discouraged for new code. From the Javadoc:

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility
> reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended
> that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of
> `String` or the java.util.regex package instead.

The `split` method accepts a regex as input. This is to split by non-words characters:

```java
public int countWordsSplit(String str) {
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return str.split("\\W+").length;
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void testWordCount(){
    String str = "Hey — how are you?\t\n";

    assertEquals(4, wc.countWords(str)); // Fail
    assertEquals(4, wc.countWordsTokenizer(str)); // Fail
    assertEquals(4, wc.countWordsSplit(str)); // Pass
}
```

### Edge cases

```
wc.countWordsSplit("Bill's house"); // returns 3

wc.countWordsSplit("1 2"); // returns 2
wc.countWords("1 2"); // returns 2
wc.countWordsTokenizer("1 2"); // returns 2

// Letters with accents, umlaut etc.
// Other edge cases...
```

### Considerations

It all depends on how you define what a "word" is in the context of your program.

Define what a word is by making some assumptions. Then find a solution that satisfies your requirements. This approach prevents you from having an over-complicated solution that your program doesn't need.

More info [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-word-counting)

Many thanks to @RolandIllig for the helpful comments.

Comment: The lonely comma is unrealistic. A string like `hey — how are you?` would be more realistic.

Comment: @RolandIllig good point, updated.

Comment: `countWordsSplit("")` — counting the words should rather be done by `findAll("\\w+")`. Unfortunately, Java's String class does not offer such a method.

Comment: @RolandIllig thanks again! Added input validation.

Comment: Still not perfect. Some more test cases are `""`, `"\t"`, `"word"`, `" 1 2 "`.

Comment: In summary, `String.split` has some surprising behavior. Therefore I prefer `findAll` over it.

Answer (score 0):

Having a single test case is by far not enough. Here are some more test cases that you should try.

```java
""
"\t"
"word"
" word "
"don't do that"
"what about hyphen-ated words?"
"and these — how many are these?"
"naïve"
"naïve"
""
```

If your code handles all of these correctly (that is: exactly as you would expect), it's good.

You should declare the method `countWords` as `public static int`. The `static` keyword means that you don't have to create an unnecessary `WordCount` object just to call this method. Instead, you can call that method as `WordCount.countWords("word")`.

In your `countWords` method, you have a bit of code duplication:

```java
str.charAt(i) == ' ' || str.charAt(i) == '\n' || str.charAt(i) == '\t'
```

In the above code, the expression `str.charAt(i)` appears 3 times. The code becomes easier understandable if you create a separate method for this purpose:

```java
private static boolean isSpace(char c) {
    return c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t';
}
```

And since it is a common task to test whether a character is a space, there's a predefined method for this. It is called `Character.isWhitespace`. You should probably use that instead of defining your own.

By the way, it is not easy to define what exactly a "word" is and how to split a text into words. Similar to defining what a "character" is. If you want to dig deeper into this topic, have a look at [Unicode Text Segmentation](https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/), which contains way more details and edge cases than you ever wanted to know.